# Composition is not rendered in Richfaces tabPanel

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I am a user of JSF and Richfaces. I will simplify the code about my question to make things easier.
I have a composition named 'mytab.xhtml' defined like following:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="header" required="true"/>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <rich:tab id="my-tab" header="#{cc.attrs.header}" >
        <cc:insertChildren />
    </rich:tab>
</cc:implementation>
```

This composition is used in another xhtml file like following:

```
<rich:tabPanel id="tp" switchType="ajax" headerPosition="top" >
     <ic:mytab id="tab1" header="header1">
          <h:outputText>content1</h:outputText>
     </ic:mytab>
     <ic:mytab id="tab2" header="header2">
          <h:outputText>content1</h:outputText>
     </ic:mytab>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

But it is very strange that the tab is not rendered at all.
To find the reason, if I add an outputText in the composition definition file like this:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="header" required="true"/>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
        <h:outputText>#{cc.attrs.header}</h:outputText>
    <rich:tab id="my-tab" header="#{cc.attrs.header}" >
        <cc:insertChildren />
    </rich:tab>
</cc:implementation>
```

The outputText will be rendered, but tab is not rendered.

Or, if I change one of the tab to richfaces tab directly:

```
<rich:tabPanel id="tp" switchType="ajax" headerPosition="top" >
     <ic:mytab id="tab1" header="header1">
          <h:outputText>content1</h:outputText>
     </ic:mytab>
     <rich:tab id="tab2" header="header2">
          <h:outputText>content1</h:outputText>
     </rich:tab>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

The first tab will not be rendered, but the second tab will be rendered.

Thank you if you could give me any help.

Comment: When you say not rendered do you mean there is no HTML generated?

Comment: Thanks @Andrei, yes, the HTML codes related to `rich:tab` are not generated.

Comment: Where did you learn about the `id="#{cc.attrs.id}"` nonsense? This makes really no sense and may potentially only cause trouble and confusion. Just give it a fixed ID which is unique within the `<cc:implementation>` itself!

Comment: Hi @BalusC, thanks for your reply. I have tried you approach just now, replaced `id="{cc.attrs.id}"` with a fixed and unique ID, but I am sorry that the problem was not resolved. Do I misunderstand your answer please? Anyhow, it happens all the time to me - if I wrap a `rich:tab` in a composition, and insert the composition in a `rich:tabPanel`, the  tab will not be rendered as a tab of the tab panel. I think the answer from @L-Ray below is right.

Comment: That was not an answer, but a comment. Please answer the question in the comment.

Comment: Hi @BalusC, I am sorry. Did you mean the question "Where did you learn about the `id='#{cc.attrs.id}'` nonsense"? I am not quite sure what's the meaning of the question, since I think I have not said it is nosense. It is very kind of you if you could explain it. Thanks.

Comment: This is not the first time I see a starter using `id="#{cc.attrs.id}"` in a composite which absolutely doesn't make any sense. So there must surely be a bad learning resource somewhere out on the Internet where you got this example from. I'd love to know about where exactly that is, so that I can contact the responsible author and tell him/her to stop spreading this misinformation.

Comment: Hi @BalusC. I got it:-) I am sorry that myself produced this error. I did not learn this from the internet. But don't worry, I did not put my bad example in any other places but only here. Let me tell my story. I just wanted to define a parameter named `id` when I was doing my work, but several days later I found it was not a good practice, since the `id` is also a build-in attribute of the composition tags. It is great that you want to find the resource that cause this error. Sometimes, people are just too rich in imaginative to make errors beyond imagination (I am not praising myself:-)).

Comment: To make sure that nobody will follow my bad practice, I have updated the question. @BalusC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composite components are rendered as own `UINamingContainer`. So between the `UITabPanel` and the `UITab`-component now is a UINamingContainer, `UITab` might not know what to do with it (same problem with datatable, by the way). What you can do is to use a [classic facelet tag](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-tags-in-jsf-2-0/) instead.