# JSR303 Bean Validation message is not displayed

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, bean-validation

I want to use JSR303 Bean Validation for my JSF+PrimeFaces frontend. I have an entity annotated with `@Size(min=2, max=5)`. When I enter some wrong input and submit the form, then the action method is not invoked, which is correct as the validation has failed, but I don't get any message on the frontend under the element. I suppose, that some messages resources are not loaded correctly.

Here is my page:

```
<h:form id="profile-form" styleClass="profile-form">
    <h2>#{txt['interview.profile.form.title']}</h2>
    <p:outputPanel id="profile-panel" styleClass="profile-panel">
        <tc:textarea id="text_de" value="#{profileBean.profile.textDe}" label="#{txt['interview.profile.text_de']}" validateBeanDisabled="true"/>
    </p:outputPanel>
    <p:outputPanel id="profile-actions-panel" styleClass="interview-actions-panel profile-actions-panel">
        <p:commandButton value="#{txt['global.save']}" action="#{profileBean.saveProfile}" update="profile-form" />
    </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

The `<tc:textArea>` is just  a composite component:

```
    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="value" required="false" />
        <composite:attribute name="label" required="false" />
        <composite:attribute name="id" required="false" />
        <composite:attribute name="validateBeanDisabled" required="false" default="true" />
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <div class="form-line float-left">
            <span class="label">#{cc.attrs.label}</span>
            <span class="input bigWidth">
                <p:inputTextarea value="#{cc.attrs.value}" id="#{cc.attrs.id}">
                    <f:validateBean disabled="#{cc.attrs.validateBeanDisabled}"/>
                </p:inputTextarea>
                <p:message id="#{cc.attrs.id}-validation" for="#{cc.attrs.id}" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </composite:implementation>
```

Here is my faces-config.xml:

```
<application>
<locale-config>
    <default-locale>de</default-locale>
</locale-config>
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>texts</base-name>
    <var>txt</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to include something else on classpath? Thanks.

Comment: probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035882/using-bean-validation-jsr-303-in-jsf2-primefaces-application could help you...        check this link also:- http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/primefaces-4-0-client-side-validation/

Comment: That is something different. I have found out that it works when not in composite component. So the problem lies in the composite component and I think the solution is somewhere around <cc:editableValueHolder /> definition in the composite component, but need to test it.

Comment: Where exactly did you learn about using the `id="#{cc.attrs.id}"` nonsense? The resource's author has to be contacted about and stopped for spreading this severe misinformation. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/21254514#comment32020611_21254514, http://stackoverflow.com/q/21302781#comment32105611_21302781, http://stackoverflow.com/q/20967953#comment32535183_20967953, etc

Comment: I haven't seen it anywhere. Read the Oracle Tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html) which is really short and explains everything on one primitive example - and there is nothing mentioned that such ID definition is wrong. And actually, I don't really understand why should it be wrong - it is an expression and it is correctly set when building the view. However, removing it and setting the id manually solved the problem.